# Accessing object values from array keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

this might be a stupid question but I'm stuck :(

I have an object and an array, one is data like this

```
var pwData = {
  "2_6": {
    "name":"ggregreg",
    "location":"Manchester",
  },
  "2_70": {
    "name":"rwerwer",
    "location":"Solihull"
  },
  "2_59": {
    "name":"Amy",
    "location":"yjhtgeg"
  }
```

and the other is a reference to an order, like this

```
var pwOrder = ["2_70", "2_59", "2_6"];
```

I'm then trying to console log some data in order of the pwOrder array, using data from pwData. Such as this.

```
 $.each(pwOrder, function(k)
{
    console.log(pwData[k].name);
}
```

Which in my mind should log peoples names from pwData in the order defined by pwOrder - however it doesn't work :( Any help much appreciated, pulling my hair out!!

Comment: When you say it doesn't work...what does or doesn't happen and what did you expect to happen? Any errors?

Comment: Is that `$.each` jQuery? If so `k` is likely to be the index rather than the value since jQuery decided to switch the order commonly used elsewhere.

Comment: It's also worth having a think about how you could have figured this out... if you put a breakpoint in your iterator function you'd be able to inspect the value of `k` on each iteration and would have quickly realised what the issue was. You could have achieved the same with a `console.log(k)` before your existing log.

Answer (score 3):

`k` in your `jquery` `each` callback will be the `index`, not the *key* itself.

```js
var pwData = {
  "2_6": {
    "name": "ggregreg",
    "location": "Manchester",
  },
  "2_70": {
    "name": "rwerwer",
    "location": "Solihull"
  },
  "2_59": {
    "name": "Amy",
    "location": "yjhtgeg"
  }
};
var pwOrder = ["2_70", "2_59", "2_6"];

$.each(pwOrder, function(index, key) {
  console.log(pwData[key].name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`jquery` is not needed for this, however, it can be done using native `javascipt`

```js
var pwData = {
  "2_6": {
    "name": "ggregreg",
    "location": "Manchester",
  },
  "2_70": {
    "name": "rwerwer",
    "location": "Solihull"
  },
  "2_59": {
    "name": "Amy",
    "location": "yjhtgeg"
  }
};
var pwOrder = ["2_70", "2_59", "2_6"];

pwOrder.forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(pwData[key].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

James is correct.

```
$.each(pwOrder, function(k)
{
    console.log(pwData[pwOrder[k]]['name']);
});
```

Works.